# Transit Time of a Boat

Tags: calculus-of-variations, optimal-control

I'm studying Variational Calculus and Optimal Control by Troutman and want to formulate Transit Time of a Boat.
we suppose the river banks parallel and utilize the coordinate system shown, in which the Y-axis represents one bank and the line X = Xl the other. We also assume that w = 1 and that the river current r is directed downstream and admits the prescription r = r(x), continuous on [0, Xl]. Then the time of transit of a boat traveling between the origin A and the downstream point $B = (x_1, y1)$ along a smooth path which is the graph of a function Y = y(x) on [0, Xl] is given by Transit Time of a Boat :
$$T\left(y\right)=\int _0^{x_1}\left[\alpha \left(x\right)\sqrt{1+\left(\alpha y'\right)^2\left(x\right)}-\left(\alpha ^2ry'\right)\left(x\right)\right]dx\:$$

> Boat : [image]

How is this formula obtained?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: Surely to be connected to the length of a curve $\int _0^{x_1}\sqrt{1+ (y')^2}\ dx$ but how ? One should know at first the **physics of the issue** ; in particular what function $\alpha(x)$ physically means  ? A drift ?

Comment: What is said in the book about this equation ? As it deals with calculus of variations, you should attempt to relate your integral with Euler-Lagrange equation $ \displaystyle {\frac {\partial L}{\partial f}}-{\frac {d}{dx}}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial f^{\prime }}=0}$ in order to find back the adequate $L$...

Comment: You will find the solution [here](http://www.acme.byu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/18-River-Crossing.pdf) (see equ. (18.3)). Also connected, this [reference](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/63674/is-there-a-closed-form-solution-to-the-esdale-river-problem).

Comment: Thank you for your answer that help me very much.